# ON DUPLICATE KEY causing deadlocks in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query to record aggregated stats for traffic according to the country of origin:

```
    INSERT INTO stats_countries (country_id, country_traffic, country_updated) 
    VALUES (?,1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    country_traffic = country_traffic + 1,
    country_updated = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Unfortunately it's running this query so frequently it seems to be causing some kind of row deadlock condition, where I have numerous connections going to sleep forever.

**Is there any way I can fix this easily while keeping the "on duplicate" condition?**

Or will I have to manually create one row for each country_id and just run a simple update?

Comment: Why not create a separate table for traffic data and assign the country ID from this table as the foreign key?

Comment: Well it is a separate table but I wanted to try creating the rows dynamically. I think I will just create a new table with all the rows already in place. Bit silly of me...